# How can I utilize asyncio to make third party file operations faster?

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, isort

I am utilizing a third party library called `isort`. `isort` has an available function that opens and reads a file. In order to speed this up I attempted to changed the function called `isort.check_file` to make it perform asynchronously. The method `check_file` takes the file path, however the current behaviour that I have attempted does not work.

```
    ...
    coroutines= [self.check_file('c:\\example1.py'), self.check_file('c:\\example2.py')]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutines))
    ...

    async def check_file(self, changed_file):
        return isort.check_file(changed_file)
```

However, this does not seem to work. How can I make the library call `isort.check_file` be utilized correctly with `asyncio.gather`?

Comment: `isort.check_file` is *synchronous function* - just wrapping it with `async` doesn't magically make it asynchronous. For such case what you really need is `multiprocessing` because even threading doesn't allow you to run python codes simultaneously due to GIL.

Comment: @jupiterbjy Isn't the entire purpose of asyncio for IO bound operations like this one? How would I adapt the code for this to work, would I need to modify the isort source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Better understanding of IO Bottleneck and GIL

What your async function `check_file` doing is just as same without `async` at front. To get any meaningful performance asynchronously, you *Must* be using some sort of [`Awaitables`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=to_thread#awaitables) - which requires `await` keyword.

So basically what you did is:

```py
import time

async def wait(n):
    time.sleep(n)
```

Which does absolutely no good for asynchronous operations.
To make such synchronous function asynchronous - assuming it's mostly IO-bound - you can use `asyncio.to_thread` instead.

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def task():
    await asyncio.to_thread(time.sleep, 10)  # <- await + something that's awaitable
    # similar to await asyncio.sleep(10) now


async def main():
    tasks = [task() for _ in range(10)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())
```

That essentially moves IO bound operation out of main thread, so main thread can do it's work without waiting for IO works.

But there's catch - Python's [Global Interpreter Lock(GIL)](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

Due to CPython - official python implementation - limitation, only 1 python interpreter thread can run in at any given moment, stalling all others.

Then how we achieve better performance just by moving IO to different thread? Just simply by releasing GIL during IO operations.

IO Operations are basically just like this:

> "Hey OS, please do this IO works for me. Wake me up when it's done."
> Thread 1 goes to sleep
>
> Some time later, OS punches Thread 1
> "Your IO Operation is done, take this and get back to work."

So all it does is *Doing Nothing* - for such cases, aka *IO Bound* stuffs, GIL can be safely released and let other threads to run. Built-in functions like `time.sleep`, `open()`, etc implements such GIL release logic in their C code.

This doesn't change much in `asyncio`, which is internally bunch of event checks and callbacks. Each [`asyncio,Tasks`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=task#asyncio.Task) works like threads in some degree - tasks asking main loop to wake them up when IO operation is done.

Now these basic simplified concepts sorted out, we can go back to your question.

---

### CPU Bottleneck and IO Bottleneck

Bsically what you're up against is *Not* an IO bottleneck. It's mostly CPU/etc bottleneck.

Loading merely few KB of texts from local drives then running tons of intense Python code afterward doesn't count as an IO bound operation.

---

### Testing

Let's consider following test case:

- run `isort.check_file` for 10000 scripts as:

  - Synchronously, just like normal python codes
  - Multithreaded, with 2 threads
  - Multiprocessing, with 2 processes
  - Asynchronous, using `asyncio.to_thread`

We can expect that:

- Multithreaded will be slower than Synchronous code, as there's very little IO works
- Multiprocessing process spawning & communicating takes time, so it will be slower in short workload, faster in longer workload.
- Asynchronous will be even more slower than the Multithreaded, because Asyncio have to deal with threads which it's not really designed for.

With folder structure of:

```
├─ main.py
└─ import_messes
     ├─ lib_0.py
     ├─ lib_1.py
     ├─ lib_2.py
     ├─ lib_3.py
     ├─ lib_4.py
     ├─ lib_5.py
     ├─ lib_6.py
     ├─ lib_7.py
     ├─ lib_8.py
     └─ lib_9.py
```

Which we'll load 1000 times each, making up to total 10000 loads.

Each of those are filled with random imports I grabbed from `asyncio`.

```py
from asyncio.base_events import *
from asyncio.coroutines import *
from asyncio.events import *
from asyncio.exceptions import *
from asyncio.futures import *
from asyncio.locks import *
from asyncio.protocols import *
from asyncio.runners import *
from asyncio.queues import *
from asyncio.streams import *
from asyncio.subprocess import *
from asyncio.tasks import *
from asyncio.threads import *
from asyncio.transports import *
```

Source code(main.py):

```py
"""
asynchronous isort demo
"""

import pathlib
import asyncio
import itertools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
from timeit import timeit

import isort
from isort import format


# target dir with modules
FILE = pathlib.Path("./import_messes")


# Monkey-patching isort.format.create_terminal_printer to suppress Terminal bombarding.
# Totally not required nor recommended for normal use
class SuppressionPrinter:
    def __init__(self, *_, **__):
        pass

    def success(self, *_):
        pass

    def error(self, *_):
        pass

    def diff_line(self, *_):
        pass


isort.format.BasicPrinter = SuppressionPrinter


# -----------------------------
# Test functions

def filelist_gen():
    """Chain directory list multiple times to get meaningful difference"""
    yield from itertools.chain.from_iterable([FILE.iterdir() for _ in range(1000)])


def isort_synchronous(path_iter):
    """Synchronous usual isort use-case"""

    # return list of results
    return [isort.check_file(file) for file in path_iter]


def isort_thread(path_iter):
    """Threading isort"""

    # prepare thread pool
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        # start loading
        futures = [executor.submit(isort.check_file, file) for file in path_iter]

        # return list of results
        return [fut.result() for fut in futures]


def isort_multiprocess(path_iter):
    """Multiprocessing isort"""

    # prepare process pool
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        # start loading
        futures = [executor.submit(isort.check_file, file) for file in path_iter]

        # return list of results
        return [fut.result() for fut in futures]


async def isort_asynchronous(path_iter):
    """Asyncio isort using to_thread"""

    # create coroutines that delegate sync funcs to threads
    coroutines = [asyncio.to_thread(isort.check_file, file) for file in path_iter]

    # run coroutines and wait for results
    return await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run once, no repetition
    n = 1

    # synchronous runtime
    print(f"Sync func.: {timeit(lambda: isort_synchronous(filelist_gen()), number=n):.4f}")

    # threading demo
    print(f"Threading : {timeit(lambda: isort_thread(filelist_gen()), number=n):.4f}")

    # multiprocessing demo
    print(f"Multiproc.: {timeit(lambda: isort_multiprocess(filelist_gen()), number=n):.4f}")

    # asyncio to_thread demo
    print(f"to_thread : {timeit(lambda: asyncio.run(isort_asynchronous(filelist_gen())), number=n):.4f}")
```

---

Run results

```
Sync func.: 18.1764
Threading : 18.3138
Multiproc.: 9.5206
to_thread : 27.3645
```

(above results are ran on NVME ssd)

You can see `isort.check_file` is not an IO-Bound operation on fast IO devices. Therefore best bet is using Multiprocessing, if *Really* needed with such fast drives.

If number of files are low in above 'Fast IO Device' situations, like hundred or below, multiprocessing will suffer even more than using `asyncio.to_thread`, because cost to spawn, communicate, and kill process overwhelm the multiprocessing's benefits.

**However** - With slow IO devics like HDD `Threading/async` is totally valid idea and will give a great boost in performance.

Experiment with your usecase, adjust core/thread count (`max_workers`) to best fit your enviornments and your usecase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From the times calculated, would this suggest that most of the time is spent inside of the `isort.checkfile` Python code, perhaps they have long calculations to determine the correct import order and then little is spent actually modifying the file in the end? 

I do wonder if the `asyncio.to_thread` counts as asynchronous given that it actually spawns threads (I was also reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316863/is-asyncio-to-thread-method-different-to-threadpoolexecutor). I was hoping for something like `await isort.check_file(file_name)`

Comment: I reran your script locally and I do get a noticeably faster time with threading.  My output was,
```
Sync func.: 32.1199
Threading : 22.7277
Multiproc.: 13.1910
```

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, this would suggest that it's mostly doing Python works rather than IO works. And `asyncio.to_thread` is not truely `Async` as you researched - but is in fact very similar in concept-wise. In fact, some libraries use it to support asyncio internally. Obviously won't work better than native Async implementation, but still is an option if asyncio is a must.

Comment: @J.Doe About results: if you have slower drives, then IO time will be longer - which means then threading starts making sense. This is why I told you to *'Experiment with your usecase'* because not everyone uses NVME drives!